# OpenVPN use auth-user-pass with a file and authenticator

Tags: vpn, multi-factor, openvpn

I have an open vpn configuration with the lines

```
auth-user-pass my-login-creds.conf
static-challenge "Enter Google Authenticator Code" 1
```

in it. When I try to connect with `openvpn my-config.ovpn` I get the error

> AUTH: Received control message: AUTH_FAILED,CRV1:R,E:a;lksjhraufhl:lasiuef/bne:Enter Google Authenticator Code

How can I make the `auth-user-pass` configuration work with an authenticator and a file containing credentials?